# Can I use downloaded content with another account?

Tags: ps3, psn

I had an account on PSN and downloaded lots of stuff on that account. But when the PSN hack happened, I forgot my password. I got my account back but still forgot my password. I got a new account that I use more often and I want all my downloads like avatars and games on that account.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you have your original back, you can download all the stuff back onto your system, and you should be able to use it with all accounts on that system.

Comment: That's correct, the only exception are avatars, that can be used only by the downloading user and not other users on the system

Answer (score 1):

Also, if your original account had any Playstation Plus content, you must have at least one active Playstation Plus account on the PS3, but the Plus content can still be used on non-plus accounts.

(I was going to add this as a comment, but don't have enough Rep)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can still play the games you download as long as you can access one of the following:
 - your psn account
 - your console account

If for some reason you can't use any of them, then no. I think the same works for DLC's and PSN games, though I'm not sure about the avatars.